# Show WFS within Leaflet view

Tags: leaflet, wfs

I have a Leaflet map where I use [Leaflet-WFST](https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST). I use WFS layers to display on the map, but since I have a lot of them, I use `new L.Filter.BBox('lin', map.getBounds(), L.CRS.EPSG4326);` so that my layers are shown in the user's visibility section. If you leave everything as it is, and when you move the map, my layers will overlap each other. This can be fixed using

```
layer.clearLayers();
map.addLayer(layer);
```

BUT it doesn't fit. I need that when moving the map into the visibility range, new layers are added and not overlapped, and those who are outside of visibility are removed.

Here is the code I am using

```
map.on('moveend', function (e) {
  layer.clearLayers();
  map.addLayer(layer);
  var layer_ = new L.Filter.EQ('layer_id', layer_id);
  var bbox = new L.Filter.BBox('lin', map.getBounds(), L.CRS.EPSG4326);
  layer.loadFeatures(new L.Filter.And(layer_, bbox));
});
```